# Getting date out of array with NSDateFormatter

Tags: objective-c

I am reading in a file of strings.  Each string looks something like:

!AIVDO,1,1,,B,11b4N?HPs0KLrBDIStg;q?w22<06,0*5A,21/10/2011 12:01:13 PM

What I have done so far is:

```
        NSArray *arrayFromString = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSString *dateString = [tempArrayFromAISString objectAtIndex:7];
//            dateString = @"21/10/2011 12:01:13 PM";

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

This returns an NSDate of (null).

The string is set ok because when I output it with NSLog it looks good.

The date formatter is ok because if I uncomment the line commented out and set the date string myself it works.

Any ideas as to why the string from the array does not work?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a newline character at the end because I was reading from a file. I fixed it with:

```
dateString = [dateString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

This gets rid of the end of line character.

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is still null.  HH is for twenty four hour time which I do not want since there is the am/pm at the end and I do not want the padding of zeros on the hour.

Answer (score 0):

Your example contains a typo. `arrayFromString`≠ `tempArrayFromAISString`

This works for me

```
NSString *theString = @"!AIVDO,1,1,,B,11b4N?HPs0KLrBDIStg;q?w22<06,0*5A,21/10/2011 12:01:13 PM";
NSArray *arrayFromString = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *dateString = [arrayFromString objectAtIndex:7];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss a"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: sorry I was changing the names to make it fit on the page better and forgot to change that.  Good catch. :)  That works for me too.  Maybe there is something that I am grabbing in the file when I read each individual string.

Comment: So fixing the typo doesn't fix the problem? or does it?

Comment: it didn't... the problem was that there was a newline character at the end because I was reading from a file.  I fixed it with dateString = [dateString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]; to get rid of the character.  Thanks again.